# Waiting for response when requesting a permission

Tags: java, android

I have to ask for a permission when starting the app, however, the rest of the app start working before there is an answer to the dialog box which leads to the problem that the activity does not get the permission to use it until it is restarted even if the permission is granted.

How can I wait for a response before continuing with the rest of the app?

Comment: Can you please post some code as to how you are asking for permission?

Comment: Probably you need to check the permission request result in onRequestPermissionsResult method and then make the rest of the job in your activity. Take a look here https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#java (Handle te permission request response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue in one of my apps, I needed to have all permissions ready on a virtual assistant chat screen. I collect Location, Audio and Storage permissions in a dummy Activity with some checkboxes that reflect their status. When my app has all three essential permissions, then, I make it jump from the dummy Activity to the main Chat Activity.
I'm pasting the entire Dummy Activity code here, it might need some cleanup, so just take what you need:

```
public class bootActivity extends Activity {

    Context ctx;
    private CheckBox checkboxLocation;
    private CheckBox checkboxAudioRecording;
    private CheckBox checkboxStorage;
    private Activity thisActivity;
    private String[] permissionsArray=new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        app.loge("BOOTING....START");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_boot);
        thisActivity=this;

        app.setBootingTRUE(getApplicationContext());
        ctx=getApplicationContext();

        //BIND UI
        checkboxLocation=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkboxlocation);
        checkboxLocation.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if(b==true) {
                    if (needPermissionLocation()) {
                        app.loge("Requesting LOCATION permission");
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity, permissionsArray,appPermissionsCallbackConstant);
                    }
                }
                refreshUI();
                if((!needPermissionLocation())&&(!needPermissionRecordAudio())&&(!(needPermissionStorage()))){
                    launchApp();
                }
            }
        });
        checkboxAudioRecording=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkboxaudiorecording);
        checkboxAudioRecording.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if(b==true) {
                    if (needPermissionRecordAudio()) {
                        app.loge("Requesting RECORDING permission");
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity, permissionsArray, appPermissionsCallbackConstant);
                    }
                }
                refreshUI();
                if((!needPermissionLocation())&&(!needPermissionRecordAudio())&&(!(needPermissionStorage()))){
                    launchApp();
                }
            }
        });
        checkboxStorage=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkboxstorage);
        checkboxStorage.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if(b==true) {
                    if (needPermissionStorage()) {
                        app.loge("Requesting STORAGE permissions");
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity, permissionsArray, appPermissionsCallbackConstant);
                    }
                }
                refreshUI();
                if((!needPermissionLocation())&&(!needPermissionRecordAudio())&&(!(needPermissionStorage()))){
                    launchApp();
                }
            }
        });

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        if(data!=null) {
            app.logy("URI:" + data.toString());
            String userinput=data.getQueryParameter("input");
            app.logy("User Input: "+userinput);
            if(userinput!=null) {
                //app.setBootingFALSE(getApplicationContext());
                app.setDeeplinkInput(ctx,userinput);
                app.logy("USER INPUT: " + userinput);
            }
        }


        if(action!=null) {
            app.logy("ACTION:" + action);
        }
        //  checkPermissions(); //launches app if permissions are OK, if not, updates permission status on the checkboxes
        app.logy("BOOTING....END");
    }//end onCreate

    boolean needPermissionLocation(){
        return ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)||
                (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED));
    }
    boolean needPermissionRecordAudio(){
        return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }
    boolean needPermissionStorage(){
        return ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)&&
                (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED));
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(requestCode==appPermissionsCallbackConstant){
            app.loge("BootActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult");
            refreshUI();

            if((!needPermissionLocation())&&(!needPermissionRecordAudio())&&(!needPermissionStorage())){
                launchApp();
            }
        }
    }

    void refreshUI(){
        app.loge("refreshUI()");
        //Refresh CHECKBOXES with permissions
        if(needPermissionRecordAudio())
            checkboxAudioRecording.setChecked(false);
        else
            checkboxAudioRecording.setChecked(true);

        if(needPermissionLocation())
            checkboxLocation.setChecked(false);
        else
            checkboxLocation.setChecked(true);

        if(needPermissionStorage())
            checkboxStorage.setChecked(false);
        else
            checkboxStorage.setChecked(true);
    }

    void launchApp(){
        app.loge("BootActivity.LaunchApp()");
        Intent i = new Intent(bootActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    final int appPermissionsCallbackConstant=1111;
    void checkPermissions(){
        app.loge("BootActivity.checkPermissions()");
        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)&&
                (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)&&
                (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)&&
                (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)&&
                (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
            app.loge("All permissions are OK");
            checkboxAudioRecording.setChecked(true);
            checkboxLocation.setChecked(true);
            checkboxStorage.setChecked(true);
            launchApp();
        }

            // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            checkboxAudioRecording.setChecked(false);
            app.loge("Requesting RECORD_AUDIO PERMISSION");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},appPermissionsCallbackConstant);
        }
        else{
            checkboxAudioRecording.setChecked(true);
        }

        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)||
                (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            app.loge("Requesting LOCATION PERMISSIONS");
            checkboxLocation.setChecked(false);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},appPermissionsCallbackConstant);
        }
        else{
            checkboxLocation.setChecked(true);
        }

        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)||
                (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
            checkboxStorage.setChecked(false);
            app.loge("Requesting STORAGE READ/WRITE PERMISSION");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},appPermissionsCallbackConstant);
        }
        else{
            checkboxStorage.setChecked(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        app.loge("BootActivity.onResume");
        thisActivity=this;
        refreshUI();
        if((!needPermissionLocation())&&(!needPermissionRecordAudio())&&(!needPermissionStorage())){
            launchApp();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        this.setIntent(intent);
    }
}
```